# error when url resource contains ampersand

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

We have a web api with the following resource url.

```
http://www.example.com/book/bookid/name/bookname
```

now there are some books which contains names with ampersand '&' and when a request is made for such names, we are receiving below error

URL used:

```
http://www.example.com/book/123/name/ban&ban
```

Error: ***A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)***

We tried passing or using encoded value for & i.e. %26 and getting same error.

URL used:

```
http://www.example.com/book/123/name/ban%26ban
```

Error: ***A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)***

Now, when I added requestPathInvalidCharacters="" property in the web.config in httpruntime element, it started working fine for both the above urls. But, when I read different articles, it is said that it is not a good practice to use requestPathInvalidCharacters="" property.

Also, since there are lot of book names in production with "&" and different special characters, we cannot avoid sending "&" ampersand for book names, is there a good way to handle this?

Comment: Perhaps you need to modify your client logic a bit to ensure an encoded URL doesn't trigger false alarms. Ideally, it shouldn't.

Comment: How to do that ?

Comment: Why do you need the name of the book in the Url if you already have a bookid?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should opt into using parameter instead of path in your querystring. For example:
http://www.example.com/book/bookid?name=Fizz&bookname=Buzz

Here's some explanation on why this exception is raised:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the article link. However, I did read this before. But avoided that route because I thought it requires code change again. And many clients have been consuming this endpoint. So, changing the above route to querystring will have lot of impact as that would be asking clients to change the url. So, I was thinking if something can be done in the code inside controller only for this endpoint. Since, there are many controllers and making a change in web.config would cause problem or make code dirty for all controllers.

Comment: The article at the link describes why it is not controller setting (request path gets processed way before the MVC parses parameters and hands it to controller). There are number of real path traversal attacks available and I'm not sure why you would want to subject your code to those vulnerabilities.